# What file is /dev/autofs?

Tags: linux, debian, centos, devices

I searched /dev/autofs from https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/admin-guide/devices.txt
I searched for /dev/autofs in  and found that it is 10,235. I used debian and stat /dev/autofs shows 10,235 but in centos it shows 10,235 in hexadecimal which is a,eb. May I ask why this is so?
This file /dev/autofs after the documentation of the explanation, only said: "Autofs control device" but does not detail the use of this file. I only know that it is a control device, But I don't know what exactly /dev/autofs controls in autofs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/dev/autofs` provides access to the `autofs` mount control interface; this is a set of `ioctl`s which can be used to retrieve information about `autofs` mounts and to configure them. See [Miscellaneous Device control operations for the autofs kernel module](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/filesystems/autofs-mount-control.html) in the kernel documentation for details.

The behaviour change in `stat` is [a bug fix](https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=48960) applied in coreutils 9.0.